# How to recover a dead Mac mini?

Tags: mac-mini, recovery, data-recovery

A friend of me just deleted everything by running `sudo rm -rf /` on his Mac mini. Yeah I know...

(Another friend of us just create a cloud virtual box and invite us to play, that poor friend asked how to play with it, I said "sudo rm -rf /" for joking but oh dear I never knew he ran it on his own Mac, now things became serious)

And Mac mini 2014 the hard disk is fixed on the board. Now what can we do to save the system and recover some important files?

Comment: Have you tried using Recovery HD?

Comment: Please add the system (version) in use (Mavericks, Yosemite or El Capitan)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the bad news, there is no simple 'un-rm'/un-delete and everything will be as it was before.

Assuming your friend doesn't have a TimeMachine Backup of the Data (hence the implied urgency), there are several steps involved:

1. Access the device
2. recover deleted files
3. rebuild the system

re 1: If you have access to another Mac and you have a thunderbolt cable, you can try to access the drive of the MacMini with "Target Disk Mode" (hold <kbd>T</kbd> on Startup, see [Apple Support here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201462)). You can then try to recover the files (Step 2), f.e. with a GUI based Software (usually commercial) like '[Disk Drill](http://www.cleverfiles.com/)', '[File Salvage](http://subrosasoft.com/OSXSoftware/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=1)' or '[Data Rescue](https://www.prosofteng.com/datarescue4/)' (of course there are others). Most of the commercial Software have a Demo-Version, so you can try before you buy.

If you don't have access to another Mac or a TB Cable you could try to start the recovery partition with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and then run the Terminal, trying to recover files via the Terminal with the methods mentioned [on this Post in 'SuperUser'](https://superuser.com/questions/133807/data-recovery-for-os-x),

If your friend is uncomfortable with the Terminal, he/you could try to install OSX on a USB-Stick or an external Harddrive and boot the MacMini from the external Drive (see [Apple Support here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204417)). You could then try to run the GUI-Software mentioned in Step 1.

Just to be clear - a recovery of Data and the OS 'in Place' (on the same Harddrive/Machine you trashed before) is not advisable, even if it would be possible. You are most likely overwriting the Data you want to recover. Your friend should have another Harddrive ready to copy the recovered Data to. After recovery we get to step 3.

re 3: After recovering the important Data to another Drive you can rebuild the System. Again, start the MacMini in recovery Mode (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) an choose Reinstall OS X (see [Apple Support here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) for detailed instructions).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your friend has a Time Machine backup, it's a simple matter to boot to the recovery partition via `Cmd`+`R` at the startup chime, then choose to restore from backup. It'll take anywhere from a few hours to quite a while to restore depending on the size of the backup set. You'll want to be on a wired network rather than trying to restore over WiFi.

If no backups of any kind exist, about all that remains is to do an Internet Recovery of the OS and start everything from scratch again. Internet Recovery is started with the same `Cmd`+`R` and then choosing to reinstall OS X.

Best of luck.